# Правописание слова "проповедует"

Tags: орфография, склонение, и

Подскажите, а то я запуталась. Как правильно писать - "проповедует" или "проповедает"? Мне казалось, что "проповедует", а сегодня в статье про американского проповедника, собирающего в России людей на квартире, попалось предложение с глаголом "проповедает". Так как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 3):

В современном языке нормативной является форма несовершенного вида **проповедовать ― проповедую ― проповедует.** Форма **проповедать ― устаревшая.**

ПРОПОВЕ́ДАТЬ, проповедаю, проповедаешь, совер. и несовер., что ( **разг. устар**.). 1. совер. к проповедовать. 2. несовер. То же, что проповедовать. [ПРОПОВЕДАТЬ | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/985502)

«Он вольность хочет проповедать.» Грибоедов.

Вы уже очищены через слово, которое Я проповедал вам. [Евангелие от Иоанна: синодальный перевод (1816-1862)]

Сравнить:

ИСПОВЕДАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; **сов.вид** Разг. =Исповедовать

ИСПОВЕДОВАТЬ, -дую, -дуешь; св. и нсв. **(двувидовой глагол)**

Answer (score 2):

Правильное написание ***проповедует***.

Формы слова:

пропове́довать, -дую, -дует

http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/propovedovat/?q=532&n=100501